# Which database table stores the order of pages?

Tags: liferay

In which database table does the order of pages get stored?

I need to get the report of the order of pages for the users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database table which stores the order of pages: **`Layout`** 
Column which determines the order of pages in this table: **`priority`**

All the different rows created will have the same **`groupId`** which determines that the pages belong to the same site (or community).
Also **`privateLayout`** column determines whether this is a private page (`column value = 1`) or public page (`column value = 0`) for the given site.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by order of pages. The pages information is stored in Layout table. For a particular set(public or private) of a group(community, org or user), the order is determined by the plid which is sorted in ascending order

Comment: I meant in my pages there is a display order for me..so where does that get stored..

Comment: in the same table as i mentioned above. There is a column called priority

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LayoutLocalServiceUtil API provided by Liferay instead of looking into the DB.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for menu items order changes, change "priority" field value in Layout table in Liferay SQL database. It worked for me.